# Passing different values in href in foreach loop (Duplicate)

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreach, get

I asked this question before but there was no response on it. So apologies. I'm asking it again

I have foreach loop here and I'm passing values from database in `view` to `controller` via `GET` route function. At first I click and send key from database to controller, then correct key is passed. By clicking second time on `<a>` tag previous key(value) is passed. I do not want to do this. I want to pass current key(value) from database. I spend 2 days in resolving this issue but failed. Do anyone know how can I resolve this issue?

Here is my code:

shopReq.blade.php:

```
@foreach($products as $key => $value)
            <div  href="{{route('special',$value->toCity)}}" id="tayyab"class="recent-container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shopping-request-modal">
                <h1>I'm opening modal and sending value to Controller.<h1>
            </div>
@endforeach
```

@include('modal')
web.php:

```
Route::get('special/{id}', [
  'uses' => 'UserController@shopReq1',
   'as' => 'special'
]);
```

UserController.php:

```
public function shopReq1($id){
    echo $id;

    $products = DB::table('shippingitems')->get();
    return view('modal',compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: may I know the structure of your $products array

Comment: @ReyNorbertBesmonte Sir, the problem is that I am not getting my desired value in `echo $id`. It has nothing to do with `$product` array.

Comment: @ReyNorbertBesmonte, I want correct and desired value in `echo $id`. But here I'm getting old value. May be this is because the page i.e. shopReq.blade.php is not refreshing. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Do you know that you will have multiple `divs` with the `id="tayyab"` in that loop?

Comment: @DanWhite yes Sir of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach($products as $key => $value)
            <div  href="{{route('special',[ 'id' => $value->toCity ])}}" id="tayyab"class="recent-container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shopping-request-modal">
                <h1>I'm opening modal and sending value to Controller.<h1>
            </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Still same problem.